# Bash: Use a variable as an array name program found but couldnt understand it can someone explain

Tags: arrays, bash, variables

I find the following program work as I wanted but I couldnt understand how it works could someone explain it for me in detail about the while loop please

```
while IFS=" " read user time; do
    eval "item=\${#$user[@]} ; $user[\$item]=\(\$((\$item + 1)),$time\)"
    [[ "${arraynames[@]}" =~ $user ]] || arraynames[${#arraynames[@]}]=$user
done<test.txt
for arrayname in ${arraynames[@]}; do
    eval "array=(\${$arrayname[@]})"
    echo "$arrayname has ${#array[@]} entries:"
    for item in ${!array[@]}; do
        echo "$arrayname[$item] = ${array[$item]}"
    done
    echo
done
```

Comment: How does `test.txt` look like?

Answer (score 0):

The `while` loop builds up a set of arrays containing the time entries for each named user in the file.

With the input separator set to a space, read each line from test.txt into `$user` and `$time`.

```
while IFS=" " read user time; do
```

Next generate and execute using the values of `$user` and `$time`.   for each line. For example let's use user=me and time=100.

So when user=me and time=100, this:

```
eval "item=\${#$user[@]} ; $user[\$item]=\(\$((\$item + 1)),$time\)"
```

Is equivalent to:

```
eval "item=\${#me[@]} ; me[\$item]=\(\$((\$item + 1)),100\)"
```

And evaluates to:

```
item=${#me[@]}                  # length of array me
me[$item]=($(($item + 1)),100)  # set last index of me to ($item+1,100)
```

Next test if `$arraynames` has "me", and adds if not.

```
[[ "${arraynames[@]}" =~ $user ]] || arraynames[${#arraynames[@]}]=$user
```

---

Some notation which may be confusing. For an array: `array=(userA userB userC)`

- `${array[@]}` - contents of the array (e.g. "userA userB userC")
- `${#array[@]}` - length of the array (e.g. 3)

Comment: HI Ben Thank you for you explanation, couple of further questions

Comment: Can I say when program first run and read a new user name and time item=\${#$user[@]} ;  is like the creation of the array and $user[\$item]=\(\$((\$item + 1)),$time\) would be the initialization of the new array

Comment: for this line [[ "${arraynames[@]}" =~ $user ]] || arraynames[${#arraynames[@]}]=$user
arraynames is like storage for all existing usernames 
"${arraynames[@]}" =~ $user  is just a way to test whether current username is in the array called arraynames right? so is that means I can write code like
if [[ "${arraynames[@]}" =~ $user ]]
then
arraynames[${#arraynames[@]}]=$user
fi?

Comment: `arraynames` is the list of all usernames. There is another array for each user. For example, if your usernames were: "userA", "userB", and "userC", the script builds an arrays for each of them and stores the names of those arrays in `arraynames`.  `${arraynames[@]}` evaluates to the _entire array_, so in this case `"userA userB userC"`, and `=~` is used to check if the value of `$user` is in that string. Your last statement means "if `$user` is in `arraynames`, then set the last index of `arraynames` to be `$user`".